# LocalHost WCF NamedPipes faults when process opened using Process.Start

Tags: c#, wcf, process, named-pipes

I have create a simple executable that hosts a WCF net.pipes service.
I can call methods on this service without error if the executable is started first.

However if the service executable is started via Process.Start, the executable starts, but the pipe proxy faults and says it is closing.

the pipe is named: net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse
and there are no credentials required to run, that I know of anyway.

Has anyone run into this issue?  It works fine if the process is started by itself, but not when started inside the program that needs to communicate.

Comment: Why not use a Windows Service? See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/876850/NetPipe-Binding-in-WCF-using-window-service) example project.

Comment: It's possible that `Process.Start` is killing the process once its done?

Comment: What kind of applications you have? Both console apps or one of them is Windows service or something UI-based? Does the application that is started via Process.Start function normally in other aspects?

Comment: Why not a Windows Service: I possibly could, but this would be extra work. The solution is to overlay a window from a 32-bit app over the top of a WCF-based, 64-bit app. The codec used does not support 64-bit.

Comment: It doesn't look like the process is being killed. When trying to send a named pipe message, the exception is could and I have looked at the Process.HasExited as well as the ExitCode and all looks good.

Comment: The 64-bit app is a WCF-MVVM based app. The other app is also WCF-based, but the main window is hidden since DirectShow will create a standard window. This is what is overlayed on the other window. The main app sends commands such as what video to load and the window location. It also sends Play, Pause, Stop, and Seek commands.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Are you taking any steps to wait for the service listener to fully open before trying to call the service?